# How to validate the user in jwt

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, netflix-zuul

I have a rest service which stores comments from the users in the database, my architecture is an angular fronted which connects to a load balancer server (zuul) which connects to an auth server to generate the jwt.
With the jwt the frontend generate the requests to the same zuul server with the jwt, this zuul server validate the jwt and if valid will connect to another backend service to store the comment.

The backend service where the comment is stored doesn't have any security validation all endpoints are accessible as the route of this microservices are not going to be exposed? Is there any risk on this?

As there is no jwt reaching the "comment backend service" how can I get the user that actually made the request? Should I implement some kind of filter in the zuul server to get the logged user from the jwt token and include the information in the request that is being sent to the "comment backend service"? If this is possible, any ideas on how to implement it?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Passtrought JWT or append additional info headers to request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Zuul considers the `Authorization` header as a sensitive header and it will not pass it downstream. So the first thing you need to do is to update Zuul configurations. Read the documentation [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#cookies-and-sensitive-headers).

After that, in each of your downstream service, you need to add the capability to read the JWT token from the `Authorization` header and extract relevant information such as username, etc.